# Como llamar a un modal desde otro archivo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap

Tengo un archivo llamado **principal.php** y tengo un modal en el archivo **alta.php**.

```html
mi boton 
----------
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="javascript:agregar();">Agregar</a>
```

```js
function agregar(){
    $('#myModal').modal({
          show:true
        });
$( "#formularioAgregar" ).submit(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var frm= $(this).serialize();
      console.log(frm);
       $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url: 'index.php?accion=guardar',
       data: frm,
       success: function(data){
        $('#formularioAgregar')[0].reset();
        window.location.replace("index.php?accion=index");
        $('#resp').html('Se Agrego Correctamente El Status').show(200).delay(2500).hide(200);
        //mostrar la respuesta del servidor
        //$('#agregar-registros').html(data);
       }
        })
    });
}
```

```html
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >&times;</button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><b>Agregar un Categoria</b></h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <form id="formularioAgregar" role="form">
                          <table border="0" width="100%">

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="control-label">Categoria</label>
                              <input type="text" name="Categoria" class="form-control input-sm" data-error="Es un campo obligatorio" required>
                            </div>
                              <input type="hidden" name="guardar" id="guardar" value="guardar">
                          </table>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                              <button type="submit" name="enviar" id="agregar" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
                            </div>
                            <tr>
                              <td colspan="2">
                                  <div id="mensaje"></div>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                   </div>
```

Como puedo acceder al modal si esta en otro archivo?

Comment: ¿Puédes mostrarnos en contenido entero de los PHP?, porque mira: Si están en una mismo document HTML por mas que estén en archivos PHP separados puedes llamarlo desde cualquier archivo JS del documento. ya que los JS se ejecutan del lado del cliente y con el HTML mostrado en cuestión.

Comment: Solo haz un **include 'alta.php'** en el principal.php

Comment: @LuisFernando gracias con el include lo trajo pero no se que paso el compañero de alado tiene el mismo codigo que yo y a el si le trae la modal , copie y pegue su codigo. pero bueno ya esta gracias

Comment: no puedo mostrar el contenido entero son como  700 lineas entre html y php en el archivo principal  disculpas ademas es  informacion de la empresa